# Xamarin "FragmentContainer does not have a view" error

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using MapBox bindings for 0.42.6 by BradKwon through NuGet.
I have a basic application and I have the app running without any issues.

When I add the NuGet to my main application in which I want to use the navigation, I have everything built 100% and it runs, until I call the Navigation Activity, it then throws the "Fragment FragmentContainer does not have a view" error and I have no idea how to trace why it does this.

I step through the application and it builds the view for the navigation but then continues through to rebuild my Home Page app from which the navigation was called and then upon this it throws the error.

I have a suspicion it has to do with conflicts of NuGet packages? But I need some guidance as to how to find where the conflicts might be and how I could go about solving that?

If I bypass the main forms and startup the application (thus not loading the references into Ram) and go straight to the navigation, it works 100%, but if I go application first, then navigation it dies...